# Why does Net::SSH2's connect method give the error "Usage: Net::SSH2::timeout(ss, timeout)"?

Tags: perl

I can connect to the server from my computer through putty, but when I use the following code, it will time out:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Net::SSH2;

my $host = "";    # this will be some host ip address

my $ssh2    = Net::SSH2->new();
my $version = $ssh2->version();

print "Version = $version\n";
print "$_\n" for @Net::SSH2::ISA;
$ssh2->connect( $host ) or die "Unable to connect to host $@ \n";

print "Something1\n";

my $stuff = $ssh2->exec( "some command" );

print "Something2\n";
print $stuff;

$ssh2->disconnect();
```

Whenever I call this, I will end up with the output of:

```
Version = 1.2.5
Exporter
Usage: Net::SSH2::timeout(ss, timeout) at       C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH2.pm line 111.
```

Also,

```
    perl -MNet::SSH2 -le"print $Net::SSH2::VERSION"
0.62
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is on line 111?

Comment: @mistermartin: It's in the `Net::SSH2` module. You can look it up on cpan.

Comment: Please show the result of `print "$_\n" for @Net::SSH2::ISA`. Thanks

Comment: @mistermartin: Line 111 of the module is `my $timeout = $self->timeout`, so the superclass of `Net::SSH2` is complaining that it requires a timeout value, when it should just return the current timeout.

Comment: Hi @borodin I am not sure how to do that if that was a question for me. I am relevantly new to perl.

Comment: @Brenden: Please just add that statement to your program before `$ssh2->connect`. Then run your program and edit your question to show the result.

Comment: Please show the output of `perl -MNet::SSH2 -le"print $Net::SSH2::VERSION"`.

Comment: @Borodin I'm getting this same error... When I add the print statement above `$ssh2->connect` I get `Exporter` .. That's it.